# YII How to Add time with number?

Tags: yii

I'll try to add  time with number where the number from variable (field estimasi=integer).

I use:

```
$model->estimasi = $estim;
$model->jamplgestim = new CDbExpression('NOW()'+$estim);
```

but get error. Anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `CDbExpression('NOW()')` shows that you want to insert this time into the sql query.
Butit does not work this way.
If you need some time point ahead, say 3 hours do this way:

```
$time = date("H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours')); // this works only for time for date too
$date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours')); //  this works only for time and date
$sql = 'Select * from <table> WHERE <time_field>  < "'. $time . '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `new CDbExpression('NOW()')` it executes it's `__toString()` method when building corresponding query. Which will out puts the constructor arguments. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbExpression#__toString-detail

Which will display as `.... jamplgestim = NOW() ...`. So in your case it'll output as `... jamplgestim = NOW()12345` which gives you a invalid sql.

If you need add some integer value to the current time, it's better to insert the full timestamp you required. eg.

```
$model->estimasi = $estim;
$model->jamplgestim = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + $estim);
```